# Not able to print more than one page with Guitar Pro 6

Tags: guitar-pro

I can't print more than one page with Guitar Pro 6 on my Mac.  Has anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to Guitar Pro 7 and can now print.